# Wierd - Android IntentService kills the rest of my app but keeps on running itself

Tags: android, android-intent, service, crash, intentservice

### I have this wierd Android issue with Services/IntentServices...

I have a Service which starts a manager class which asks for ActivityRecognition updates from Google Play Services (i.e. gets a connection, then calls requestActivityUpdates() on ActivityRecognitionClient passing a PendingIntent).

The PendingIntent references an IntentService with onHandleIntent(Intent) implemented - it just prints the most probable current physical activity to the Log.

So far so good. Everything works fine - the Service is bound, the Manager connects, the IntentService is fired and the users physical activity is written to the Log.

### Here's the problem...

I want this to just sit in the background and listen for activity updates, even if my user shuts down the UI activity in the 'recent apps' screen. This technique I already use in my app for location updates - my location service keeps tracking location even if the UI portion of the app is destroyed by the user or the system.

Thing is, since adding this new Activity recognition stuff, when the user kills the UI, the next PendingIntent received by the IntentService kills, the entire rest of the App including all the other services. Everything stops/dies/disappears. But there are no warnings, no exceptions, no log entries, no nothing!

The only thing that keeps on working is the damned IntentService! That keeps going like nothing happened every time a new Intent comes in.

If I comment out the code where I register for activity updates (so the PendingIntent isn't used and the IntentService doesn't get called) everything works just fine.

I have no idea what's possibly causing this meltdown, and no clues to go off in the Log.

I searched and searched Google / SO but I've drawn a blank. I can't find anyone describing similar behaviour.

So is there another type of Android component capable of being triggered by an Intent that I could try instead of IntentService? Is IntentService realy the problem? Can Activity recognition not be done in the background like this? What other things could I try?

**Update:** Is it possible that when the onHandleIntent() method on the IntentService finishes, the OS kills all threads in my app, not just the one created for the IntentService?

Here's what's in the Log...

```
--User is shutting down the App UI, but the Services are left running as intended...
19:41:12.146  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.TripComputer? STOPPED TripComputer Activity: 1107344720
19:41:12.153  1258-4401/? W/ContextImpl? Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1244 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114
19:41:12.645  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.TripComputer? DESTROYING TripComputer Activity: 1107344720
19:41:12.646  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.services.JourneyServiceConnectionManager? Activity 1107344720 is STOPPING the JourneyService...
19:41:12.652  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.services.JourneyServiceConnectionManager? IGNORING request to STOP the JourneyService - Journey in progress.
19:41:12.655  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.services.ActivityServiceConnectionManager? Activity 1107344720 is STOPPING the ActivityService...
19:41:12.657  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.services.ActivityServiceConnectionManager? IGNORING request to STOP the ActivityService - Activity in progress.
19:41:12.659  13679-13679/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.TripComputer? DESTROYED TripComputer Activity: 1107344720

--The UI has closed down sucessfully. 
--The next activity update arrives at the IntentService and gets printed...
19:41:19.703  13679-14095/tripcomputer I/tripcomputer.services.ActivityUpdateIntentService? The most probable user Activity is still (50)

--Then, the system kills the IntentService?
19:41:19.704      969-979/? I/ActivityManager? Killing 13679:tripcomputer/u0a152 (adj 0): remove task
19:41:19.706    1258-4401/? W/ContextImpl? Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1244 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.ProcessKillTrigger.sendTrigger:147 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.ProcessKillTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:164

--Boom!, everything else has gone but there's nothing in the Log
--System schedules the Crashed Services for restart
19:41:19.727     969-1273/? W/ActivityManager? Scheduling restart of crashed service tripcomputer/.services.JourneyService in 1000ms
19:41:19.736     969-1273/? W/ActivityManager? Scheduling restart of crashed service tripcomputer/.services.ActivityService in 1000ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I did eventually find an alternative method that worked...**

The problem I experienced above may to be to do with how IntentService threads are handled, although unfortunately I didn't ever track down a more concrete explanation for the total loss of the running app when the intent service's handleIntent method finished.

The workaround was to switch to using a combination of a regular Service to handle the ActivityRecognition PendingIntents (in onStartCommand(Intent...)) along with a custom made Runnable thread to handle the actual work offline from the UI thread. If you do this, the app no longer quits unexpectedly and you get the desired effect.

It's interesting that the documentation and sample code for Google Play Services' Activity Recognition feature only ever mentions working with user activity recognition from an android Activity or a Fragment and never from a Service. Could it be that working with activity recognition using IntentServices can only be done from components running on the UI thread???

Comment: Mind adding the code that you wrote in `onStartCommand()`? Want to know how you combined both.